# Find average time between multiple datetime objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I want to find the average time a client visit at particular location. My data structure is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5aea9f9a83b391f80e00a1b1"),
  "Client": "ABC",
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-03 10:47:42"
 },
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5aea9f9a83b391f80e00c1a1"),
  "Client": "ABC",
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-03 11:05:04"
 }  ,
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5aea9f9a83b391f80e00a1e1"),
  "Client": "ABC",
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-03 13:05:04"
 }  ,
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5aea9f9a83b391f80eaea1e1"),
  "Client": "DEF",
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-03 11:20:44"
 }
```

I have just tried code so far in codeigniter

```
$optn = array(
        array('$group' => array( '_id' => '$Client', 'date1' => array('$min' => '$Timestamp'), 'date2' => array('$max' => '$Timestamp'), 'avg_time' => array('$avg' =>  array('$subtract' => array('$date2', '$date1')))))
    );
$repeatdata = $this->mongo_db->aggregate("logsdata", $optn);
echo '<pre>';  print_r($repeatdata);
```

It gives me result as:

```
 Array
    (
[waitedMS] => 0
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [_id] => ABC
                [date1] => 2018-05-03 10:47:42
                [date2] => 2018-05-03 13:05:04
                [avg_time] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [_id] => DEF
                [date1] => 2018-05-03 11:20:44
                [date2] => 2018-05-03 11:20:44
                [avg_time] => 
            )
     )
  )
```

Comment: Your `Timestamp` values are "strings" and not dates. You would need to convert them to be BSON Date values in order to do that.

Comment: @NeilLunn, but i am getting these as responses from some third party. So is there any way to sorted out in this way

Comment: Does not matter where you :"got them from". MongoDB **needs** them to be BSON Date. So it's up to "you" to convert your data. Ideally as you import it from the "third party". You [sort of can](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) do some "casting", but the format still needs to be specific and doing this an runtime is not efficient, nor the intended usage. Fix the dates in your collection, is the real thing to do here.

Comment: @NeilLunn, as you suggest, i changed my Timestamp value to "Timestamp": ISODate("2018-04-27T18:29:45.0Z") but still i am getting 
([_id] => ABC
                    [date1] => MongoDate Object
                        (
                            [sec] => 1524850772
                            [usec] => 0
                        )
                    [date2] => MongoDate Object
                        (
                            [sec] => 1524850773
                            [usec] => 0
                        )
                    [avg_time] => 
                )